# Two processes sharing the same heap

Tags: c, fork, heap-memory

I haven't understood something about processes generated with fork().
If I try a code like this one:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* mem=malloc(100);
    pid_t pid=fork();
    printf("%p\n",mem);
}
```

Both processes print the same address.
So do they point at the same area of memory in the heap?
Isn't that dangerous? There may be a conflict.
My book says that the values on the stack are copied, but it does not talk about heap.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different processes are contained in separate virtual address spaces so those memory addresses point to different memory locations.

As Karoly Horvath suggests, it is a bit more complicated due to an optimization called [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), which basically allows having a single copy until a distinction is needed. This is implemented through page-faults and in the end same addresses in two separate virtual address spaces do not refer to the same memory location.

Comment: No, they point to the same hardware address till you write in it. When you do a fork(), the OS marks all the pages in the memory to create a page fault on write. This write is catched and only then the actual copying takes place. As long as you're only reading from the memory this works just fine and saves precious memory and CPU time ;)

Comment: You should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

The environment, resource limits, umask, controlling terminal, current working directory, root directory, signal masks and other process resources are duplicated from the parent in the forked child process.